# Having problems with a trigger and its test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, update

I have been working on this trigger for the past day and a half and I cannot seem to get it to work how I need it to. I have done triggers before and can usually figure out what needs to be done with a little help as they are updating fields on a single object. However, with this trigger I am trying to write (Updating two objects) I keep hitting errors and obstacles. If anyone could provide me any information or help to get this done it would be greatly appreciated.

This is the trigger I have written:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert)
{

    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {
         contactIds.add(c.ContactId);
    }

        //Update Contacts
        Map<ID, Contact> mapContacts = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact where Id IN :contactIds]);
        System.debug(mapContacts);
        List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        For(Case caseOb : Trigger.new)
        {
            Contact cont = mapContacts.get(caseOb.ContactId);
            cont.Country__c = caseOb.CountryWebFormText__c;
            contactToUpdate.add(cont);
    }

    update contactToUpdate;

    Map<Id, Contact> mapUpdatedContacts = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    For(Contact cons : contactToUpdate)
    {
        mapUpdatedContacts.put(cons.Id,cons);
    }

    //Update Cases
       List<Case>  caseList = [SELECT Id, CountryWebFormText__c, Newsletter__c, Country_of_Origin__c  FROM Case];
List<Area__c> areaList = [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c];
List<Case>  bulkifyList = new List<Case>();
    for(Case caseObj : caseList)
    {
        for(Area__c a : areaList)
        {
            if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name.equals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c))
            {
                caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;
                bulkifyList.add(caseObj);
            }
        }            
    }

    update bulkifyList;
```

What this trigger is supposed to do is:

1. Check if Case.CountryWebFormText__c matches any Area__c.Name record
2. If it does then Case.Country_of_Origin should equal Area__c.Name as should
   Contact.Country__c be equal to Area__c.Name

This is my test class though the insert statement doesn't work when I test it in execute anonymous so I have not gone any further with it:

```
@isTest
public class WebToCaseCountryTest
{

    public static testMethod void testTrigger()
    {

        Case caseObj = new Case(Id = caseObj.Id, CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
        insert caseObj;
        System.debug(caseObj);

        System.assert(caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c == caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c);


    }
}
```

This is the error I get when executing the insert statement in execute anonymous: Line: 2, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, WebToCaseCountry: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: CA Trigger.WebToCaseCountry: line 28, column 1: []

Comment: You added the test class so is that a new question? Are you now saying your trigger is working as expected? Please close this question out and create a new one for the test class.....

Comment: Okay thanks @Eric I just didn't want to overload on the questions but I will open a new one.

Comment: Okay thanks @Eric I just didn't want to overload on the questions but I will open a new one.

Comment: No worries. Easier to answer focused questions that to try and thread them together in one question.....Also it keeps the code etc in context with the current state so the group can answer the questions more effectivly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it; probably contains typos:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert) {

    Set<String> countries = new Set<String>();
    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if (!String.isEmpty(c.CountryWebFormText__c) {
            countries.add(c.CountryWebFormText__c);
        }
    }

    if (countries.size() > 0) {
        Set<String> filteredCountries = new Set<String>();
        for (Area__c a : [select Name from Area__c where Name in :countries]) {
            filteredCountries.add(a.Name);
        }
        if (filteredCountries.size() > 0) {
            Case[] caseUpdates = new Case[] {};
            Contact[] contactUpdates = new Contact[] {};
            for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
                if (filteredCountries.contains(c.CountryWebFormText__c)) {
                    caseUpdates.add(new Case(
                            Id = c.Id,
                            Country_of_Origin__c = c.CountryWebFormText__c
                            ));
                    if (c.ContactId != null) {
                        contactUpdates.add(new Contact(
                                Id = c.ContactId,
                                Country__c = c.CountryWebFormText__c
                                ));
                    }
                }
            }
            update caseUpdates;
            update contactUpdates;
        }
    }
}
```

Probably needs the `Newsletter__c` flag check adding but that wasn't included in the description. The overall logic is problematic where a `Contact` is related to multiple `Case` objects as the last update will win.

Comment: Thank you for that Keith, easy to understand. I am writing the test class but getting an error with the insert statement, would you mind checking why this might be? I had this happen with my old trigger code as well leading me to believe it might be something simple that needs changing. I edited my original post to include the test class. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nik `System.StringException: Invalid id` sounds like you were assigning a non ID value .e.g a name to an ID field or variable. But I can't see anything obvious. The line number matters - check the exact line number in your current code.

Answer (score 5):

I have simplified it to do what you wanted.

Points:

1. You do not need to query for the contacts as the ID already exists on the case object
2. Your context should be a before insert
3. Gather the list of Area names in a collection
4. consolidate things where needed

   ```
   trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (before insert){

   //Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
   Map<ID,Contact> conTBU = Ne Map<ID,Contact>();    
   //From your code it seems you do not need a map as a set of Names should work but just in case
   Map<String,Area__c> areaList = New Map<Stirng,Area__c>();

   //Get the areas by string for later use **Note: Best if this could be a custom setting or have a utility to reuse this
   for(Area__c a : [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c]){
       areaList.put(a.Name,a);
   }


   for(Case c : trigger.new){
       if(areaList.containsKey(c.CountryWebFormText__c)){
           if(c.ContactID != null){
               if(conTBU.containsKey(c.ContactID))
                   //Code to handle multiples cases for the same contact
               else
                   conTBU.put(c.ContactID,New Contact(id=c.ContactID,Country__c = c.CountryWebFormText__c));
           }

           if(c.Newsletter__c == TRUE && c.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL){
               c.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;
           }
       }
   }

   update conTBU.values();
   }
   ```